# Make a navbar hide with ng-hide/ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I can´t this navbar to show just one of the navbars, it shows both of them. What am I doing wrong?

View:

```
    <!-- Logged in -->
    <div ng-show="loggedIn">
      Navbar logged in
    </div>

    <!-- Logged out-->
    <div ng-hide="!loggedIn">
      Navbar logged out
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'userService',
  function($scope, $state, userService) {

    $scope.loggedIn = userService.isLoggedIn();

    $scope.login = function() {
      userService.login();
      $state.go('home');
    };

    $scope.logout = function() {
      userService.logout();
      $state.go('login');
    };

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "!" of the ng-hide:

```
<!-- Logged out-->
<div ng-hide="loggedIn">
  Navbar logged out
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the condition

```
<div ng-hide="!loggedIn">
```

to

```
<div ng-show="!loggedIn">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix this with better performance, you don't need to keep the hidden navbar in the DOM, you can use:

```
<!-- Logged in -->
<div ng-if="loggedIn">
  Navbar logged in
</div>

<!-- Logged out-->
<div ng-if="!loggedIn">
  Navbar logged out
</div>
```